# Como concatenar nome de variáveis em Java

Tags: java, variáveis, concatenação-de-string

Estou com uma dúvida. Estou querendo gerar um total de variáveis, a partir de um `for`, para não ter que escrever todas elas, mas não estou conseguindo fazer a concatenação dos nomes de variáveis.

Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
     String nome + i = null;
}
```

Gostaria de ter um retorno de:

```
nome0 = null;
nome1 = null;
nome2 = null;
nome3 = null;
```

- Há a possibilidade de criar várias variáveis com uma estrutura de
  repetição?
- Por qual o motivo, não funciona dessa forma?

Comment: Por que não usa o `string[]`? Ainda mais que vai trabalhar com uma estrutura `For`, é melhor codificar usando Arrays...

Comment: @VictorLaio é que a intenção, não é criar um array para os valores, mas várias variáveis com nomes diferentes, coloquei na questão somente um exemplo de uso.

Comment: Se você está trabalhando com campos de uma classe, é possível fazer isso com o uso de reflexão e [getDeclaredField()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)). Mas dependendo do caso de uso, seria melhor pensar em utilizar alguma estrutura de dados, como sugerido (array, ou map).

Comment: Arrays, listas e `Map`s foram criadas para isso. Mas se por algum motivo você não quer ou não pode usá-los, então suspeito que você não sabe exatamente o que quer fazer ou o porquê. Veja mais sobre isso em [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

Comment: Pretendia fazer um comentário, mas minha pontuação não permite... A resposta do usuario está correta, não é possível fazer isso em Java. Provavelmente há uma estrutura de dados mais indicada para o que você pretende. Se tiver alguma dúvida a respeito de um caso específico pode postar outra pergunta... Boa sorte!

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu tenho conhecimento dessas estruturas, só queria saber se era possível criar dessa forma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso não e possível. Não há variáveis ​​dinâmicas em Java. As variáveis ​​Java precisam ser declaradas no código-fonte.

O resultado mais próximo que você pode conseguir e usando `ArrayList`, `String[]` ou um `Map`.

Como:

```
List<String> nomes = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    nomes.add(null);
}
```

ou:

```
int tamanho = 4;

String[] nomes= new String[tamanho];

for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
    nomes[i] = null;
}
```

ou:

```
Map<String, String> nomes = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    details.put("nome" + i, null);
}
```

É possível usar a reflexão para referenciar dinamicamente variáveis ​​que foram declaradas no código-fonte. No entanto, isso só funciona para variáveis ​​que são membros de classe (isto é campos estáticos e de instância). Não funciona para variáveis ​​locais.

No entanto, fazer esse tipo de coisa desnecessariamente em Java é uma má ideia. É ineficiente, o código é mais complicado e, como você está confiando na verificação em tempo de execução, ele é mais frágil.

E isso não é "variáveis ​​com nomes dinâmicos". É melhor descrito o acesso dinâmico a variáveis ​​com nomes estáticos.

Comment: é que a intenção, não é criar um array para os valores, mas várias variáveis com nomes diferentes, coloquei na questão somente um exemplo de uso.

Comment: Como dito, você não conseguirá criar em Java nomes de variável dinamicamente. Talvez valha a pena você descrever o que quer fazer com isso, e o pessoal pode sugerir um outro caminho para você seguir.

Comment: boa explicação, essa era a dúvida se dava para criar dessa forma, ou somente utilizando essas estruturas